# How can I detect which programs (names) are currently minimized using Python 3 / cmd on Windows 10?

Tags: python-3.x, windows, batch-file, cmd

I'm working on an app with Python for my grandma to make Windows simpler for her to use.

I need to know which programs are minimized to maximize them and also get some information about them. I saw some answers how to keep all windows maximized, but I can't understand how to get information about minimized windows.

Comment: you'll need P/Invoke and [GetWindowPlacement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getwindowplacement) function. Similar thing I've done [here](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/.net/c/windowMode.bat) though I'm setting the mode ,but not getting it.

Comment: I'll try to write a script for this If I have the time today.

Comment: See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-enumwindows as the most reliable way of returning top level windows. For VBA ported to VB.NET code see command line utility that prints out all windows using a slightly different approach (because it does child windows) see https://winsourcecode.blogspot.com/2019/05/winlistexe-list-open-windows-and-their.html.